# Зачем нужен readonlydictionary если есть ключевое слово readonly?

Tags: c#, .net

Какой смысл существования ReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>, если существует обычный Dictionary<K,V> с ключевым словом readonly?

Comment: Эти `ReadOnly...`/`readonly` означают разные вещи.

Comment: доп информация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46911392/4423545

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что

- `ReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>` создаётся заполняется в конструкторе и больше содержимое `ReadOnlyDictionary` не меняется.
- `readonly Dictionary<K,V>` создаётся один раз присваивается больше не меняется ссылка, а содержимое `Dictionary` изменяется.

В первом неизменна содержимое, во втором ссылка.

Comment: В целом понятно. Но в ссылке которую скинули выше  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911211/whats-the-difference-between-a-readonlydictionary-and-an-immutabledictionary/46911392#46911392 есть упоминание того что можно изменять ReadOnlyDictionary путем изменения Dictionary с помощью которого он был создан. Плюс ReadOnlyDictionary в том что прямо это сделать нет возможности.

Comment: @John В целом чтоб руки не чесались. Если конечно постараться то пожно и причесать :). Идея проста чтоб не меняли содержимое. Там заглушки стоят которые скинут исключение при попытке вызова вот и вся история. По факту обертка, декоратор или как там кому удобно